# Opening camera with a navigation tab

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera

I just started using Android Studio to develop an experimental application. My current problem in trying to get one of my navigation bar tabs set to a camera tab so that when  pressed, the camera opens, user takes a picture, then the program does something with that picture. However, when I tried to set the tab as a camera, the program immediately crashes after clicking on the tab. I have this portion of the code currently set as my Main for that specific tab.

```
case R.id.navigation.dashboard:
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
```

Should I use a button as an alternative?

EDIT: changed title and some details to the question for more clarification

EDIT2: Got the problem fixed, thanks! The problem for me was actually not checking for app permissions manually via the app info even though I had these permission scripts on the XML file already.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

So I forgot to add a permission popup on my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of thing are wrong with this:

1. Why use tabs for camera if you are just going to use an intent for the camera picture.
2. The intent should look something like this:

Note: imageUri should be set here to be used later

```
void takePhoto(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "image.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

3. Since starting an activity for result you need to declare a variable TAKE_PICTURE:

   ```
   private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 123
   ```
4. Maybe you want to use tab for showing the picture, and that can look like this:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PICTURE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                Bitmap bitmap;
                try {
                     bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                     .getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);

                    // show image here in an imageView

                     } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Gah, I'm very sorry about the wording, I meant to write "using on the of the navigation bar tabs" instead normal tabs if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to open new `Activity` you can use CameraX library.
[Here](https://github.com/android/camera/tree/master/CameraXBasic) you have nice sample how to use it.